# I am starting a new job on Monday. Can they screw me over somehow with the information I need to provide? Does this look sketchy to anyone else?

Tags: canada, scams, ontario, job-offer

Congratulations! You have accepted for a trial period on the Remote Executive Manager position.

blahblahblah

During the work you use bitcoins for working with customers.
It is necessary for customers. Use the services of our partners at a lower price, you can only for business purposes.
Services and goods which you will buy for customers through bitcoins for low price:

- Web Design;
- MySQL Database;
- Set up VoIP number;
- Database Servers;
- Stock exchange services;
- Hosting;
- Virtual private servers.

"To start working with Bitcoin, you need to fill up your wallet. We will provide you money via e-Transfer Interac system.

To do this, we need to know:
Your Holder name:
Your Bank name:
Your Email address associated with account:
Your phone number:

There is no fee to receive bitcoins, and many wallets let you control how large a fee to pay when spending. 
Most wallets have reasonable default fees, and higher fees can encourage faster confirmation of your transactions. 
After receiving electronic transfer, you will have to fill up your Bitcoin wallet.

We will send you 2-3 transactions through Interac system.
Have you ever used electronic transfer (Interac)?
Do you have online banking active?
Do you have business bank account?"

Comment: "We will provide you money via e-Transfer Interac system. To do this, we need to know: Your Holder name: Your Bank name: Your Email address associated with account: Your phone number: ". The only thing needed to make an Interac eTransfer to someone is any valid email or mobile phone number.

Comment: If this were a real job, I would expect the company to give YOU details of THEIR account, which they would give you access to for the duration of your employment.  Asking the employee to provide the account would be a logistical nightmare when the employee quit or otherwise departed the company's employ.

Answer (score 11):

“Remote” job position plus “bitcoin” = scam. I’m sorry - your best bet at this point is to block them, delete any messages and move on. If you have already given them any of your personal information then you may need to watch your credit report, and definitely change any passwords if you have given those out.

Comment: The only difference with this is, They don't want me to cash a cheque or accept anything, it is interac e transfer to my bank, I have auto deposit so I don't risk clicking any malicous websites. Is this still a red flag?

Comment: Definitely still a red flag.

Comment: Yep, still a red flag. Most likely, the money they transfer you will come from someone else’s account or other criminal activities and you will be part of a money laundering operation.